# decimal or enumeration in a single type

Tags: xsd

Is it possible to define an XSD type that can contain any valid decimal number OR one of a set of predefine values.

For example, if I wanted an attribute that could contain either a number or one of these strings: "max", "min"

This document would be valid:

```
<elem attr="123.456"/>
<elem attr="max"/>
<elem attr="-768.456"/>
```

While neither of the elements in this document would be valid:

```
<elem attr="hello"/>
<elem attr="0x2D"/>
```

For min and max specifically I had planned to use `float.MaxValue` and `float.MinValue` (C#) but it seems that XSL has issues with exponentials - i.e. it doesn't recognise them at all.

There may be other ways around that however for the purposes of this question I'd like a generic answer where the enumeration could contain any number of pre-defined strings.

Comment: Have you though about using a XML Schema Regular Expressions Restriction?

Comment: I hadn't, in  fact It didn't occur to me that XSD can do regexes. I'll bare that in mind in future however I prefer sergioFC's answer as being less hacky :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XSD allows you to define a *simpleType* from the union of other *simpleType* using the ***xs:union*** element.

```
<xs:simpleType name="unionType">
    <xs:union memberTypes="xs:decimal myEnumeration">
    </xs:union>
</xs:simpleType>
```